Symbolic logic notation for super-set: $B\supset A$?

$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
\text{set theory notation}  & \text{symbolic logic notation}\\ \hline
A\subset B & \forall x(x\in A\rightarrow x\in B)\\ \hline
B\supset A & ?\\ \hline
\end{array}$

In the above table, the set theory notation for set $A$ being a subset of set $B$ is denoted by $A\subset B,$ and the translation to symbolic logic notation is along the lines of $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow s\in B)$.  For the corresponding superset notation $B\supset A$, what is the corresponding symbolic logic notation?

EDIT

Maybe I'm missing something, but why would it not be the same as for $A⊂B$ ?

So, $A⊂B$ is equivalent to $∀x(x∈A→x∈B),$ while $B⊃A$ is equivalent to $∀x(x∈B←x∈A)$ ?

Maybe I'm missing something, but why would it not be the same as for $A \subset B$?

I think you mean "$\dots x \in B)$" in the upper-right entry.  Also, the lower-right entry should be the same thing as the upper-right entry.

@EricTowers thank you for noticing my typos.  I fixed it.

@PrincessEev I think super set in symbolic logic notation, i have never seen it before.  I can't simply be $B\supset A$

Why not? That's the definition I'm most familiar with. In general, whenever we define some ordering $\prec$ (e.g. $\subset$), we often conventionally define the horizontally-flipped version (here, $\succ$; for you, $\supset$) by
$$
a \succ b \iff b \prec a
$$
much like how
$$
x < y \iff y > x
$$

It's just like $3<7$ can also be written $7>3$.

So $A\subset B$ is equivalent to $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow x\in B)$ and $B\supset A$ is equivalent to  $\forall x(x\in B\leftarrow x\in A)$?


So, $A⊂B$ is equivalent to $$∀x(x∈A→x∈B),$$ while $B⊃A$ is equivalent to $$∀x(x∈B←x∈A)$$ ?

Yes; as a matter of fact, since $\text‘A⊂B\text’$ and $\text‘B⊃A\text’$ are equivalent to each other, both of them can be written as $$∀x(x∈A→x∈B),$$ which is indeed interchangeable with $$∀x(x∈B←x∈A),$$ like how $\text‘2<5\text’$ and $\text‘5>2\text’$ are interchangeable.

thank you for clarifying that up for me.

actually, there is just one minor notational issue I want to ask you about.  In the case of $\forall x(x\in B\leftarrow x\in A)$, iis that equivalent also to $\forall x(x\in B\vee x\not\in A)$?  Thank you in advance.

@Seth Yes, they are logically equivalent. (Glad to be of help!)
